# Prove subspace and subsets or R are polish space

Tags: general-topology

"Let a,b∈R, with a < b. Prove that each discrete subspace of R and each of the spaces [a,b], (a,b), [a,b),(a,b], (−∞,a), (−∞,a], (a,∞), [a,∞), and {a}, with the topology induced as a subspace of R, is a Polish Space."

This question is a bit confusing. What exactly are discrete subspace of R? Is it just any subset or R with the discrete topology?

Also, Polish space means separable and completely metrizable, but just because R is complete under the usual Euclidean metric doesn't mean a subspace is complete so I must be confusing something.

Comment: A toplogical space is Polish if there is a metric which induces the given topology and makes it a complete, separable metric space.

Comment: Any $G_{\delta}$ subset of a  Polish space is Polish.

Comment: "Discrete subspace of $\Bbb{R}$" means a subset $X$ such that the usual topology on $\Bbb{R}$ induces the discrete topology on $X$. (The challenge here for such an $X$ is to show that it is finite or countably infinite.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each discrete subspace $D$ of $\Bbb R$ is at most countable, and has the discrete topology as its subspace topology (that's the definition of being discrete), and this topology can be induced by the discrete metric $d_1(x,y)=1$ whenever $x \neq y$, and this metric is complete (every $d_1$-Cauchy sequence is eventually constant, and hence converges). So $D$ is Polish (separable, due to its size) and completely metrisable.

Indeed $\Bbb R$ itself is Polish (it's usual metric will show that, and $\Bbb Q$ is countable and dense), and hence so is every closed susbet of $\Bbb R$: we just inherit the metric and the subspace is still sepaarble and compleet in the inherited metric, by standard facts. This handles sets like $[a,b]$, $[a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,a]$ e.g. and also $\{a\}$ (it's discrete too BTW).

$[a,b) \simeq [a,\infty)$ so if one is Polish so is the other (being Polish only dpends on the topology; it's preserved by homeomorphism), etc. $(a,b) \simeq \Bbb R$ is Polish for the same reason.

Comment: Ok I understand that all intervals contain the rationals so they are separable and closed subsets of complete metric space are closed under the induced topology so that also makes sense, but I still dont get why (a,b) is a Polish space. The usual euclidean metric does not make this complete.

Comment: @William it’s homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ via a $\tan$ like function e.g. completely metrisable means there exists some metric that makes it complete; this doesn’t need to be the original metric.